# How To Scrape This Field From Webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code goes into a webpage, and takes certain data from **each row**

I however want to also get the "topics" from each row. For example listed as "Presidential Session and Community Psychiatry" in row 1, above the "Speakers" text.

My code is currently able to scrape Titles and Chairs of each row (denoted as Role and Name) but not the topic?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://s7.goeshow.com/apa/annual/2021/session_search.cfm?_ga=2.259773066.1015449088.1617295032-97934194.1617037074')
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.select('#datatable')
for table in tables:
    for title in table.select('tr td.title'):
        print(title.text.strip())
        title_row = title.parent
        speaker_row = title_row.next_sibling
        for speaker in speaker_row.select('span.session-speaker'):
            role = speaker.select_one('span.session-speaker-role').text.strip()
            name = speaker.select_one('span.session-speaker-name').text.strip()
            topic=speaker.select_one('span.session-track-label').text.strip()
            print(role, name,topic)

        print()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please add a representative sample of the HTML you are dealing with.

Comment: hello, https://s7.goeshow.com/apa/annual/2021/session_search.cfm?_ga=2.259773066.1015449088.1617295032-97934194.1617037074

Answer (score 0):

inside speaker for loop you are searching elements under "span.session-speaker"  element there is no element  "span.session-track-label" under that element

use:

```
tables = soup.select('#datatable')
for table in tables:
    for title in table.select('tr td.title'):
        print(title.text.strip())
        title_row = title.parent
        speaker_row = title_row.next_sibling
        for speaker in speaker_row.select('span.session-divider-line'):
            role = speaker.select_one('span.session-speaker-role').text.strip()
            name = speaker.select_one('span.session-speaker-name').text.strip()
            topic = speaker.select_one('span.session-track-label').text.strip()
            print(role, name, topic)

        print()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, when i run this, this only prints the title/role?